# How to count table column values and print in blade file laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with `laravel 5.6` and I have table named `vehicles` with columns `categoryname`:

```
id   number  categoryname
1    123       Car
2    589       Van
3    589       Car
4    563       SUV
5    563       Van
```

Now I have following `blade` view in `welcome.blade.php`:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('/images/car.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" height="50" width="50" class="center-block">
                        <div>Car</div>

                        <div>text text text texttext texttext texttext text trtrttr rrttrtr rrtrttr rtrtrttrtr rtrttrtr rrtrttr rrtrtr</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/van.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" height="50" width="50" class="center-block">
                        <div>Van</div>

                        <div>text text text texttext texttext texttext text trtrttr rrttrtr rrtrttr rtrtrttrtr rtrttrtr rrtrttr rrtrtr</div>
                        </div>
```

My problem is now I need count same values in `categoryname` column and print them like this way in `welcome.blade.php`.

```
<div>Car</div>
<div>2</div>

<div>Van</div>
<div>3</div>

etc...
```

I have following controller to count column values:

```
$names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();
```

It is working however I need `print` its values under vehicles `categories` in blade file.

How can I achieve this?

**Image**
[image: weicome.blade.php file here]

**hope to do this dynamicaly with relationship**
I have 2 models as Category and Vehicles with following relationship Category

```
public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class);
    }

public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

and categories table name as following

```
id   categoryname   images
1   Car             car.png
2   Van             van.png
3   SUV             suv.png
etc
```

then how can I print categoryname and images from categories table and categoryname values counts using vehicles table and print all in same loop?

Comment: what data you are getting in `$names`

Comment: categoryname columns counting values

Comment: just pass $names variable to view and use loop to display the result

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: @KrishnaJoshi if I use loop I am unable to print vehicle images with regarding to categorynames values because images put statics way not dynamic from table

Comment: Then i would suggest you to make the images dynamic as well

Comment: @KrishnaJoshi see screen shot

Comment: please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `groupBy()` in Controller:

```
$names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get()->groupBy('categoryname');
```

In Blade:

```
@foreach($names as $key => $name)
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('/images/'.$name->images) }}" alt="{{ $key }}" height="50" width="50" class="center-block">
        <div>{{ $key }} ({{ $name->count() }})</div>
        <div>text text text text</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

*Keep image name same as the category name.

Comment: then how can I print vehicle images regarding to My categorynames values

Comment: please see screen shot of my current view file

Comment: @banda answer edited...try now...& if the answer helps you please mark this as correct.

Comment: No it is not what I need because some discriptions are diffrent to different vehicles. any way I hope to use relationship vehicle and category models to print this please see my edited answer

Comment: Listen Mr @banda this is not a tutorial website or a freelancing site where people write code for other. You are continuously editing your question and add a new question here. We can't write your whole application. This is not the way we help. You must be know how to programming. There are lots of stuff out there. If you need more go hire a freelancer.